# CSS / Show not the class which is not class

Tags: css

Is it possible to hide all elements of an class which are not the same as the class. i tried the code below but its not working.

```css
li.show *>:not(.show) {
 display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly? something like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/e1s2qsw1/?

Comment: Current code is targeting the child of the show class, not the show class itself.

Comment: There is a <ul> with multiple classes. <li class="1"> and <li class="2"> and <li class="3">

I want to hide every <li> which is not <li class="1">

Comment: classes and ids cannot start with num http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors you will not be able to target them

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/e1s2qsw1/1/ like this?

Comment: that was a example for showing what i want. Lets say it is:

 <li class="hello"> and <li class="my"> and <li class="name"> I want to hide every <li> which is not <li class="hello">

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/e1s2qsw1/1/ ?

Comment: why not hide all `li` and explicitly show class `hello`?

Comment: It looks like https://jsfiddle.net/dfs30pjn/

Comment: The side is http://zweiundvierzig.de/klinikum/
It is at the bottom of the Screen.

every code i tried caused that the whole jobblock is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your fiddle is that you write `<div>` instead of `</div>` everywhere, which causes all the content to end up in the first div in the li.

Solution: correct all the errors, then it will work as expected.

```css
.show1 :not(.show1),
.show2 :not(.show2) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="show1">
    <div class="show1">show1</div>
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
  </li>

  <li class="show2">
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
    <div class="show2">show2</div>
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
    <div class="hide">hide</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want like this.?

```css
ul.hello>li:not(.hello){
    display : block;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
ul.hello>li.hello{
    display : block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hello"> 
    <li>with multiple classes.</li>
    <li class="hello"> and</li>
    <li class="aetw"> and</li>
    <li class="hello"> I want to hide every </li> 
    <li class="sdf"> and</li>
    <li class="hello"> I want to hide every </li> 
</ul>
```

here is jsfiddle
**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k5wkbqou/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
li.show *:not(.show) {
    color:red;
    /*display: none;*/
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e1s2qsw1/2/)